# paper-item, center item correcly inside it

Tags: javascript, polymer, flexbox

I'm trying to position some content inside an `paper-item`, more precislely I'm trying to horizontal-center and vertical-center the content but it won't work. I'm probably doing something very simple wrong.

Here's the code:

```
  <paper-item style="background: blue; height: 200px;">
    <div horizontal layout center style="background: green;" flex>
      <div style="background: red; text-align: center;" flex>
          Lägg till
      </div>
    </div>
  </paper-item>
```

Result:
[image]
Expected Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add style to you template

```
<style>
    paper-item::shadow .button-content {
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `self-center` attribute, but it's parent element in this case a `div` must have it's height set explicitly.

Example:

```
<paper-item style="background: blue; height: 200px;">
    <div horizontal layout center style="background: green;" flex>
      <div style="background: red" center-center self-center flex>
          Lägg till
      </div>
    </div>
</paper-item>
```

More about layout-Attributes at: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html

Comment: Thanks, but that solution aint working. If I for example set the height to be 100%, it will overflow the paper-item for some reason. The only way this "works" is if i set it to the same size as the paper-item minus the padding that the paper-item have.